# Java Data type for storing astronomical numbers

Tags: java, data-structures, largenumber, large-data

So I like to think about large numbers like [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number). And a part of that is occasionally coming up with fast growing functions my self.

I always like to try out these functions and since Java is my goto language I need a way to store really really large numbers. I would have an idea for a fast-growing-function like:

```
f(a,b,c) = f(a-1,f(a-1,b-1,c),f(a-1,b-1,c-1))+1 
f(0,b,c) = f(b,b-1,c)+1 
f(0,0,c) = f(c,c,c-1)+1 f(0,0,0) = 1 
f(x) = f(x,x,x)
```

And see how fast it grows. I would kinda graph f for a few natural numbers to see how fast it grows. It would be ok if that printed in a format of

```
f(0)=... 
f(1)=... 
f(2)=...
...
```

Where the ... can really be anything that gives me an idea of the scale of the number (the number of digits, an approximation in any notation,...)

### Data structures that won't work

BigInteger won't cut is since it stores a number with integer precision so with 8GB of ram it is limited to around 2^2^30.

BigDecimal won't cut it either since it stores a BigInteger exponent so numbers around 2^2^2^30.

So obviously you can't store numbers with perfect precision (with any method) that would require way to much memory. But I don't need exact precision I just need a really really large scale.

I was thinking about a datastructure like:

```
class Number {
   long base;
   Number power;
}
```

This will store number on the order of 2↑↑MemorySize ([Arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)) but for functions like a↑↑↑b it will ultimately fall short.

But is does have some nice properties to speed up calculations.
mainly that a^b * c^d = a^(b+d*alog(c))
and alog(c) can be evaluated as 2log(c)/2log(a) or around d/b (assuming the exponent is always updated so the base is around 2)
so you you get a^b * c^d ~= a^(b+d²/b) which is a lot faster
this works for higher order operations too (although I forgot the exact formula)

You can maybe devise a way to store numbers as a*2↑↑b but that will fall short eventually to.

### Any good solution?

Is the best option really to convert the number to a notation you know you won't exhaust like [Conway chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) for functions slower than f<sub>ω²</sub>(n)?

And how would you even go about adding numbers like that?

Or should you store numbers directly as an ordinal and an argument for the [fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy)?

Is there a library or class that does something like this? Really anything that works better (and a lot faster) than BigDecimal would already be a huge help.

Comment: At the fundamental level you will only be able store numbers with exact precise as well as `BigInteger`. If you have 100 bytes then that is 800 bits and they can be in exactly one of 2^800 states. So you can't store more than 2^800 numbers or two numbers have the same state. On that basis I don't quite understand what you can do that will satisfy you.

Comment: I don't need exact precision I just need a really really large scale. I though that was pretty clear with "So obviously you can't store numbers with perfect precision that would require way to much memory."

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with these numbers?  Compare them?  Do math with them?

Comment: It was only clear that you realised that method wouldn't work not necessarily clear you realised no method would work.  But understood.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I mainly want to test if the fast growing functions I came up with really work. For example: I would come up with an idea like:
f(a,b,c) = f(a-1,f(a-1,b-1,c),f(a-1,b-1,c-1))+1
f(0,b,c) = f(b,b-1,c)+1
f(0,0,c) = f(c,c,c-1)+1
f(0,0,0) = 1
f(x) = f(x,x,x)
And would like kinda graph f for a few natural numbers to see how fast it grows.
It would be ok if that printed in a format of
f(0)=...
f(1)=...
f(2)=...
...

I will add this to the main question

Comment: @Persixty if it wasn't perfectly clear I will add it to the main question

Comment: The universe is barely 10^27 meters so anything larger isn't astronomical. `BigInteger` magnitude is restricted to 2^(2^31-1) which takes only(!) 256MB and `BigDecimal` does not use `BigInteger` exponent, it uses `int` scale (exponent of 10) hence (2x10)^(2^31-1)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I only used astronomical because I couldn't think of a bigger word to describe them. My numbers might have been of by a 2^... or so but that really doesn't matter on this scale. I suggest you look into grahams number if you want to really understand what I mean. (Too be contunued)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 
I think I messed up on the calculation of BigInteger but if it has perfect precision. It needs 1 byte per 4 binary digits. So 1GB is around 4 billion digits or around 2^30 digits or 2^2^30 values. Tell me what I did wrong.

And an int exponent for BigDecimal is even worse. I didn't really do my research properly on that part I just figured it could be at most a BigInteger

Comment: `BigInteger` is stored in binary using `int` limbs ('limb' is the accepted if weird-sounding term for bignum's form of 'digit') = 32 bits in 4 bytes = 2G bits in 256M bytes.